# How to pass data from server/manager to viewmodel RxJava Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am very new to RxJava and I'm working on an Android app with it. I am making a network request and I'd like my Fragment to update the UI based on the network returned data, and I'm looking for a good 'rx' way to do this. Basically I have my Fragment immediately firing to my viewmodel that it should make the server call. I need to make the server call and notify/send that data to the viewModel so that I can update it to the fragment. Normally (without rx), I'd just pass all of this data with variables, but how can I achieve this data flow using rx and observables?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate Repository layer, access it only from your viewModels.

In this way you will have view/databinding triggering requests.

Next, have some State management inside Repository or store some data there(use LiveData)

In your ViewModel assign value to the ref of LiveData from repository. So anytime you update it inside Repository - viewModel will have the same object.

Finally, you can observe that viewModel's LiveData.[image]

`val someData = MutableLiveData<SomeObject>()` - this one inside repository, now you will be able to save any network call result inside repository.

Have your ViewModel contain next one: `val someData= Repository.instance.someData`

And from fragment/activity use : `viewModel.someData.observe(this, {...})`

Comment: Fantastic response, thanks Max. Let me see if I can get this right - make the request and set the liveData in the repository layer, and have the ViewModel contain a reference to that liveData? What would this look like in Code?

Comment: Hey, Is it right to refer same live data object that is generated by the repository layer. It is like activity/fragment accessed the repository live data object indirectly. I think according to MVVM model, it must not be like this. Activity/fragment must use view model's live data. For this we should use Mediator live data or something else. Please clarify  me on this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Going to show simple example with code. Another way of doing this using concept single source of truth (SSOT).

Activity-->ViewModel--->Repository--->Insert On Room DB

1. Step 01: Get all data from room database with Live Data query. And set adapter.
2. Step 02: Call from Activity/Fragment to remote database/repository to get data.
3. Step 03: After getting data from remote repository insert it to room database.
4. Step 04: You have already observing data with Live Query on step 01 so as soon as you 
        insert data on room database your live observe query will fire again and update 
        your listview.

Now following example is not complete. But to get a rough idea.
To call & update List using LiveData.

```
Activity/ Fragment:

RouteViewModel mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RouteViewModel.class);      
mViewModel.getAllRoutes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Route>>() {
@Override
public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Route> items) {
            // will call automatic as soon as room database update
            adapter.setItems(items);
        }
});

//init/write a remote call here (like you called on room database)

--View Model

public LiveData<List<Route>> getAllRoutes() 
{  
  //call here reposatory
  return mAllRoutes; 
}

//also write another method here to call repo to init a remote call

---Repository
public LiveData<List<Route>> getRoutes() {
       //call on Dao
        return mRouteDao.getRoutes();
    }


//init a remote call 
public Observable<Route> getRoutesFromNetwork(int routeID) {

    return new NetworkService().GetChannel().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String result) {

                    List<Route> items = new Gson().fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<Route>>() {
                    }.getType());

                    Completable.fromRunnable(() -> {

                //insert routes
                //if routes is Live data it will update ui automatic

                    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete() {
                                    Log.v("Completed", "DONE");
                                    Toasty.info(context,"DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                    Log.v("Error", "Error");
                                }
                            });

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });



}
```